# Aurelia: can't link a controller to my navigation bar template

Tags: aurelia, skeleton-code, aurelia-templating

I started playing around with Aurelia (which is really nice), but quickly ran into an issue for which I cannot immediately find a solution.

I am using the Aurelia Skeleton projects from Github. Specifically I am using ESNext + WebPack. But my problem is consistent amongst the other projects as well.

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack

The project includes a `nav-bar.html` file which builds links based on the `router` configuration. However I want to add custom logic to this navigation bar, in the form of an inline login form. Thus I need to attach a `controller` to it.

Normally, in Aurelia this is done by creating a file with the same name as is mentioned everywhere. So I create `nav-bar.js` and put all the logic there. But that doesn't work here... the `nav-bar.js` file is not picked up and doesn't get connected to the template.

What's more is that I found out that none of the templates which I `<require from="./myTemplate.html">` work with a controller in this project. Only the templates loaded in the router work with a controller.

That leads me to think that I'm missing some configuration that needs to be set up ... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requiring HTML, require by name only:

```
<require from="./myTemplate"></require>
```

When you use `.html` extension that hints the templating engine that you want to load view-only component, without view model. You can read more in Aurelia [documentation hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/7).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works indeed. I understand this is mentioned in the docs but the docs are huge and I don't think I would have found this detail in there easily. :)